# TFS Build Script Definition - Not Getting Latest Code

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild, definition

For one of our build scripts (TFS 2013), when we run it manually or during Check-In (Continuous Integration trigger), the build script is not picking up the latest code changes. We looked in the logs and it does have the correct changeset number for the impacted files (in this case .vb files). We tried with several different .vb files. We also tried recreating the build script from scratch to no avail. We have several other build scripts for similar web applications that have no issues with the same build settings. This project builds fine. We set the Clean Build to True. Configurations is set to "Any CPU|Release". Output Location is set to SingleFolder. Build Template is set to TfvcTemplate.12.xaml. Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, one last item. When we made a change to a .aspx page, it included it in the drop from the build script version. We only see this occurring for the code behind files.

Comment: A little bit confuse about your issue: 1). What's the build script about? 2). How do you check the build doesn't pick up the latest code changes? You mentioned that the correct changeset number can be found in the build log.

Comment: You can open the logs in the drops folder. It details out what the build grabbed for files and appends the changeset number on the end. For example, we'll make a change to the one.vb file and check it in under C12345. Then in the logs you can see that the build retrieved the file from the C12345 changeset. When we then look inside the .dll the change is not in there.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a bit of kicking the tires we figured it out. We had the actual compiled .dll in this case checked into TFS. Hence, the build server would grab the old version that was checked in versus compiling the project on the fly. We removed the .dll from source control to resolve the issue.